# sharing a file via public link

Tags: apex, sharing, attachment

Let's say we have a student object. Under Student Object, we have multiple files attached (such as certifications, etc).

I want to expose public link for each files of each student. So that outside system can consume the file via public link.

1) How can I set public link for files every time file is created dynamically.

Each file for each student should be unique.

Any possible approach for this requirement in Salesforce?

Comment: Where do you want to expose that link? Do you have a site? Customer portal?

Comment: that is another portal which will consume the file via the public link. All I need is to expose the public link for each attach file in salesforce. I am stuck at this point, don't know how to set it up.

Answer (score 1):

I use this method on our site and customer portal to expose documents. I'd say this should work for attachments as well as long as the sharing setting for the record allow.

```
<a href="{!URLFOR($Action.Document.Download, recordID )}">Download</a>
```

Comment: hi. There is no link for [Download]. Can you fix it?

Comment: Ok. I have fixed it

Comment: You can probably try:
<a href="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, yourattachmentID )}">Download</a>